# VB.Net: rotating base64 image in memory

Tags: vb.net, image

I have a `base64 image` and I have to rotate it, encode and save it again on the server.
This is my code:

```
Function Rotate As Boolean(ByVal encoded As String)
    Dim decoded, decoded2 As String
    Dim ms As MemoryStream
    Dim img As Bitmap    

    decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(encoded)
    ms = New MemoryStream(decoded)
    img = Image.FromStream(ms)
    img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone)
    img.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    decoded2 = ms.ToArray

    Return decoded2.SequenceEqual(decoded)
  End Function
```

Try with

```
 Rotate("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")
```

The problem is that `decoded` and `decoded2` are identical. If I change the line `img.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormt.Png)` with `img.Save("C:\test\test.png", Imaging.ImageFormt.Png)`, the image on the disk is correctly rotated. Why?

Comment: Speculation: You don't reset the position of the memory stream after `FromStream`, so it's possible that `Save(ms, ...)` just *appends* the rotated image to the stream. Have you tried using a different (new) MemoryStream instead? It would also improve code readability (`msSource` and `msRotated` are more explicit than `ms`). BTW, `decoded2 = ms.ToArray` is incorrect - you try to assign an array to a string variable. Did you mean to write `decoded2 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())`? If you haven't already done so, enable `Option Explicit` - it easily catches those kinds of errors.

Comment: I have tried to use different memory streams, same result. About the second error, was just a copy error. The correct declaration is Dim decoded(), decoded2() As Byte

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] (including a tiny Base64-encoded image in the code that demonstrates the problem)?

Comment: I have edited my code